# How to get React Component Link tag to span 100% of li tag?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

For some reason, my ` tag won't stretch to 100% of my li tag.

Here is the CSS I have for this dropdown menu

```
    .dropdown-menu {
      background: red;
      width: 200px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 80px;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .dropdown-menu li {
      background: #ff3734;
      padding: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
 

    .dropdown-link {
      background: lime;
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Here is my dropdown component and the className for the Link tag is "dropdown-link"

```
      function Dropdown() {
        const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

        const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);

        return (
          <>
            <ul className={click ? 'dropdown-menu clicked' : 'dropdown-menu'}>
              {MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <li key={index}>
                    <Link
                      className={item.cName}
                      to={item.path}
                      onClick={() => setClick(true)}
                    >
                      {item.title}
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                );
              })}
            </ul>
          </>
        );
      }
```

[image]

There's this spacing around the lime green Link tag that I don't know what it's happening?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't your li tags that are the problem. Can you change the li background to blue?

Comment: Can you please add codesandbox link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be because of the `padding: 16px;` in `.dropdown-menu li`.

Comment: ah that fixed it! Thanks